# Node: req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access the things that I send from req.body in nodejs but it always comes as undefined I have tried using body-parser still it shows undefined.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/parts', (req, res) =>{

    console.log('In app.post with id:'+ req.body.id + ' name:'+ req.body.name); // shows undefined in id and name
    const part= parts.find(c=>c.id === parseInt(req.body.id)); 
    if(!part) {
    console.log('part not found and to be inserted/pushed -current lenght:'+ parts.length);
    const p= { id:parseInt(req.body.id), name:req.body.name};
    parts.push(p);
    console.log('parts lenght:'+ parts.length); 
    console.log(parts);       
    res.send(parts[parts.length-1])
}
    else {
    console.log('Part with ID '+ req.body.id+ ' exists already');
    res.status(404).send('Part with ID '+ req.body.id+ ' exists already')
}
})
```

Here is my postman Body:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"abcd"

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending it via POST with the right `Content-Type`?

Comment: Verify if the content type that you are setting inside postman is set to application/json

Comment: yeaa there was issues in postman i was sending text instead of JSON.